# Get rid of "object" wrapper in django rest framework serialized SearchQuerySet

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I serialise Django Haystack's SearchQueryStack with DRF as following, and in resulting JSON response i want to get rid of object wrapper around my Post model:

```
{
"count": 6, 
"next": null, 
"previous": null, 
"start_index": 1, 
"end_index": 6, 
"num_pages": 1, 
"results": [
    {
        "postWrapper": {
            "hitcount": {
                "counter": 9, 
                "id": 251
            }, 
            "id": 277, 
            "content": "test", 
            "owner": {...
```

This is JSON i want (there is no postWrapper):

```
    {
"count": 6, 
"next": null, 
"previous": null, 
"start_index": 1, 
"end_index": 6, 
"num_pages": 1, 
"results": [
    {
            "hitcount": {
                "counter": 9, 
                "id": 251
            }, 
            "id": 277, 
            "content": "test", 
            "owner": {...
```

This is view:

```
class PostSearch(generics.ListAPIView):
model = Post

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # simplified filtering of an SQS
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=q)
    paginator = Paginator(sqs, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    serializer_context = {'request': request}
    serializer = PaginatedPostSerializer(posts, context=serializer_context)
    ret = serializer.data

    return response.Response(ret)

class SearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
object = PostSerializer()

def to_representation(self, obj):
    """
    Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes.
    """
    ret = OrderedDict()
    fields = [field for field in self.fields.values() if not field.write_only]

    for field in fields:
        try:
            attribute = field.get_attribute(obj)
            if field.field_name == 'object':
                field.field_name = 'postWrapper'
        except SkipField:
            continue

        if attribute is not None:
            ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

    return ret
```

Here are serializers:

```
class SearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    object = PostSerializer()

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        """
        Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes.
        """
        ret = OrderedDict()
        fields = [field for field in self.fields.values() if not field.write_only]

        for field in fields:
            try:
                attribute = field.get_attribute(obj)
                if field.field_name == 'object':
                    field.field_name = 'postWrapper'
            except SkipField:
                continue

            if attribute is not None:
                ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

        return ret


class PaginatedPostSerializer(pagination.PaginationSerializer):

    start_index = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    end_index = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    num_pages = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='paginator.num_pages')

    class Meta:
        object_serializer_class = SearchSerializer

    def get_start_index(self, page):
        return page.start_index()

    def get_end_index(self, page):
        return page.end_index()

    def get_curr_page(self, page):
        return page.number
```

Here is PostSerializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)
    category_edit = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    price = serializers.CharField()
    price_currency = serializers.CharField()
    hitcount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def get_hitcount(self, context):
        # Content_type for Post is 20
        c_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(context)
        obj, created = HitCount.objects.get_or_create(content_type=c_type, object_pk=context.id)
        data = {}
        data["id"] = obj.pk
        data["counter"] = obj.hits
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('hitcount', 'id', 'content', 'owner', 'category', 'category_edit', 'images', 'price', 'price_currency')
```

As you can see closest I could get is to rename 'object' wrapper to 'postWrapper'. I want to remove it completely as a wrapper, so there'd be only Post model list inside 'results', which contains 'hitcount', 'id', 'content', 'owner' etc...

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the*output* you need, this is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added this to my PostSearch view and it solved my issue:

```
    ret = serializer.data
    new_result_list = []
    results = ret.get('results')
    for orderedDict in results:
        post = orderedDict.get('object')
        new_result_list.append(post)

    ret['results'] = new_result_list
```

Basically I made a new list without 'object' wrapper and put it back to return value.

Answer (score 0):

I think just use `PostSerializer` as your `object_serializer_class` in your `PaginatedPostSerializer` is what you want.

```
class PaginatedPostSerializer(pagination.PaginationSerializer):
      class Meta:
            object_serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

If you wanna override the the `to_representation`, you can **extend** the `PostSerializers` instead of adding it as a new field to the new serializer.

p.s.: If you wanna wrapper the result item in a `postWrapper`, you don't need to override the `to_representation` function, you can just rename it in your `SearchSerializer`:

```
class SearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # object = PostSerializer()
    # rename the object to what you want
    postWrapper = PostSerializer()
```

I think I got a misunderstanding of your queryset looks like, so make the answer above.

```
class SearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    object = PostSerializer()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        res = super(SearchSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        # pop of the object field, and push the fields inside the object to parent level
        objectfield = res.pop('object', None)
        if objectfield:
            for field, value in objectfield.iteritems():
                res[field] = value
        return res
```

IMHO，To change your queryset to a `Post` model queryset, and set the paginatedSerializer's object_serializer_class to `PostSerializer` makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If set _PostSerializer as object_serializer_class_ I get _'NoneType' object has no attribute 'concrete_model'_ error. 

And the second suggestion leads only to the array of empty _postWrapper_ objects. 

Sadly.(

Comment: @NBayaman I added a new solution to my answer... anyhow, I can't finger out the reason about  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'concrete_model' error ....

Comment: Please review my solution. So far it solves my issue.